# "Invalid use of member... Did you forget the &?" Accessing class objects in another class obejct

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to write my own NeuralNetwork, and I use my own Matrix2D class for the operations. I'm trying to write out the values of the neural neutworks first weigth matrix but I get an error like: 161|error: invalid use of member 'Matrix2D NeuralNewtork::first_hidden_weights()' (did you forget the '&' ?)|

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

float RandomNumber()
{
    return ((((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX))*2)-1);
}

class Matrix2D{
    public:
        int rows;
        int columns;
        float **matrix;
        Matrix2D(int x, int y){
            rows = x;
            columns = y;
            matrix = new float*[rows];
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                matrix[i] = new float[columns];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                    matrix[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        Matrix2D randomizeMatrix(){
            Matrix2D result(rows, columns);
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                    matrix[i][j] = RandomNumber();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        static Matrix2D scalarMultiply(Matrix2D x, float y){
            Matrix2D result(x.rows, x.columns);
            for (int i = 0; i < x.rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < x.columns; j++) {
                    result.matrix[i][j] = x.matrix[i][j] * y;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        static Matrix2D scalarAddition(Matrix2D x, float y){
            Matrix2D result(x.rows, x.columns);
            for (int i = 0; i < x.rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < x.columns; j++) {
                    result.matrix[i][j] = x.matrix[i][j] + y;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        static Matrix2D scalarSubstraction(Matrix2D x, float y){
            Matrix2D result(x.rows, x.columns);
            for (int i = 0; i < x.rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < x.columns; j++) {
                    result.matrix[i][j] = x.matrix[i][j] - y;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        static Matrix2D matrixAddition(Matrix2D x, Matrix2D y){
            Matrix2D result(x.rows, x.columns);
            for (int i = 0; i < x.rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < x.columns; j++) {
                    result.matrix[i][j] = x.matrix[i][j] + y.matrix[i][j];
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        static Matrix2D matrixTranspose(Matrix2D x){
            Matrix2D result(x.columns, x.rows);
            for (int i = 0; i < x.rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < x.columns; j++) {
                    result.matrix[j][i] = x.matrix[i][j];
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        static Matrix2D matrixMultiplication(Matrix2D x, Matrix2D y){
            Matrix2D result(x.rows, y.columns);
            for (int i = 0; i < result.rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < result.columns; j++) {
                    float sum = 0;
                    for (int k = 0; k < x.columns; i++) {
                        sum += x.matrix[i][k] * y.matrix[k][j];
                    }
                    result.matrix[i][j] = sum;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        void printMatrix(){
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
                }
            cout << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
};

class NeuralNewtork{
    public:
        int numberof_input_nodes;
        int numberof_hidden_layers;
        int numberof_hidden_nodes;
        int numberof_output_nodes;
        Matrix2D first_hidden_weights();
        Matrix2D* hidden_weigths();
        Matrix2D output_weights();
        Matrix2D* hidden_biases();
        Matrix2D output_biases();

        NeuralNewtork(int input_nodes, int hidden_layers, int hidden_nodes, int output_nodes){
            numberof_input_nodes = input_nodes;
            numberof_hidden_layers = hidden_layers;
            numberof_hidden_nodes = hidden_nodes;
            numberof_output_nodes = output_nodes;

            Matrix2D first_hidden_weights(hidden_nodes, input_nodes);
            first_hidden_weights.randomizeMatrix();

            Matrix2D* hidden_weigths[numberof_hidden_layers-1];
                for (int i=0; i<numberof_hidden_layers-1; i++){
                    hidden_weigths[i] = new Matrix2D(numberof_hidden_nodes, numberof_hidden_nodes);
                    hidden_weigths[i]->randomizeMatrix();
                }

            Matrix2D output_weights(numberof_output_nodes, numberof_hidden_nodes);
            output_weights.randomizeMatrix();

            Matrix2D* hidden_biases[numberof_hidden_layers];
                for (int i=0; i<numberof_hidden_layers; i++){
                    hidden_biases[i] = new Matrix2D(numberof_hidden_nodes, 1);
                    hidden_biases[i]->randomizeMatrix();
                }

            Matrix2D output_biases(numberof_output_nodes, 1);
            output_biases.randomizeMatrix();
        }
        Matrix2D feedForward(Matrix2D input){

        }

};

int main()
{
    srand (time(0));
    //Matrix2D myMatrix(3,7);
    //myMatrix.randomizeMatrix();
    //myMatrix.printMatrix();

    NeuralNewtork nn(4, 3, 5, 1);
    nn.first_hidden_weights.printMatrix();     //<=This line gives the error:

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to print out the first_hidden_weight Matrix2D obejcts matrix component to see if my code is working the way it's intended, but I get an error when I try to access that variable.

Comment: `nn.first_hidden_weights` is a method, to call it -> `nn.first_hidden_weights()`

Comment: Unrelated: your constructor creates a *local variable* `first_hidden_weights` instead of affecting the class variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you defined all your weights as zero-argument functions that return a Matrix2D as opposed to member variables. Drop the `()`.

Secondly, your constructor creates and initializes *shadow variables*, which are completely decoupled from your member variables.
Use the `=` operator to explicitly initialize them:

```
first_hidden_weights = Matrix2D(hidden_nodes, input_nodes);
```

For the `hidden_weights` and `hidden_biases` members, I suggest you use `std::vector<Matrix2D>`. This automates memory management and gives you a bunch of handy methods. You might initialize `hidden_weights` like so:

```
hidden_weights.reserve(numberof_hidden_layers-1);
for (int i=0; i<numberof_hidden_layers-1; i++){
    hidden_weights.push_back(Matrix2D(numberof_hidden_nodes, numberof_hidden_nodes)); // or use emplace_back
    hidden_weights.back().randomizeMatrix();
}
```

Finally, since you seem to call `randomizeMatrix` a lot after construction, consider making an explicit constructor that automatically randomizes:

```
enum class Randomize { Randomize };

class Matrix2D {
...
  Matrix2D(int x, int y, Randomize)
  : Matrix2D(x, y) { // delegate to the simple constructor
    randomizeMatrix();
  }
...
};
```

You can then simply write something like `Matrix2D(x, y, Randomize)`.